# Can't get rewrite to work correctly for lighttpd + webpy (through fastcgi)

Tags: webserver, fastcgi, lighttpd, web.py

I can't seem to get rewrite to work for lighttpd + fastcgi. I'm running a webpy app which is located at /var/www/training/trainapp.py

/var/www is lighttpd's docroot

My fastcgi config looks as follows:

```
# /usr/share/doc/lighttpd-doc/fastcgi.txt.gz
# http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs:ConfigurationOptions#m$

server.modules += ( "mod_fastcgi" )
server.modules   += ( "mod_rewrite" )

 fastcgi.server = ( "/trainapp.py" =>
 (( "socket" => "/tmp/fastcgi.socket",
    "bin-path" => "/var/www/training/trainapp.py",
    "max-procs" => 1,
   "bin-environment" => (
     "REAL_SCRIPT_NAME" => ""
   ),
   "check-local" => "disable"
 ))
 )

 url.rewrite-once = (
   "^/favicon.ico$" => "/static/favicon.ico",
   "^/static/(.*)$" => "/static/$1",
   "^/(.*)$" => "/trainapp.py",
 )
```

When I use the config file above everything works as expected, when I go to `http://ipaddress/` the webpy app is opened. However, when I change rewrite line of the config file to:

```
url.rewrite-once = (
   "^/favicon.ico$" => "/static/favicon.ico",
   "^/static/(.*)$" => "/static/$1",
   "^/flip/(.*)$" => "/trainapp.py",
 )
```

and go to `http://ipaddress/flip/` I get an error that says "not found". It is different from a regular 404 error; lighttpd usually responds with "404 - Not Found" for the `http://ipaddress/flip/` I only see a non-formatted "not found" message.

The following pastebin shows the lighttpd log for the two scenarios. I can't find the source of the error from this, it seems as if they are handled both in the same way, however one ends in a 404.

http://pastebin.com/E3qzEAzD

Anyone any idea of what I'm missing here? Thanks.

Comment: Is there any chance your `trainapp.py` is returning the 404? The request handling makes it look like everything goes smoothly to `trainapp.py` in both cases.

Comment: No, there is nothing in trainapp.py that can do this. Tried the same with nginx and Apache2, both do this without problems.

Comment: Hi Bart, Did you find any solution to your problem? I am facing the same issue!

Comment: @user732362 Unfortunately I didn't, in the end I simply switched to Apache2.